# Nodejs temporary data store

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have large json object that I wanted to store on the server temporarily, which is between the round trips from client to server. How can I do that in NodeJs. I've tried saving that to my DB (mongo) using the expression-session that i'm using in my application, but because of its size (I believe, because with small amount of data it is working fine without any problem) getting my application is not able to read that object back whereas it is reading everything else in to the session. Is there an alternative to preserve the data between round trips, right now I'm sending that huge data to the client unnecessarily and bringing it back to the server which is a overhead. Any help is appreciated. This is the first time i'm dealing with MEAN stack.

Comment: I would likely use Redis as a caching layer.  How big is the object in question?

Answer (score 4):

Redis might be useful in this regard, but remember it is an in-memory data store. So big data == big memory usage.

go look at [node-json-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-db). It is a file-based key-value store that retrieves and saves data as quick as your hard drive can handle. *it also has a sweet "path-based" query structure that makes it very easy to manage*

Answer (score 0):

you can store data inside your file on server and can fetch and retrieve easily later after task complete you can delete it .

Answer (score 0):

You may also use express-session package to store temporary data in the server for every client, you dont even need to do a client log-in for that. But the catch is **that you must use one of the compatible session stores**, if you use the memoryStorage that comes with express-session it will fail constantly, specially for production.

Right know I'm using this [memorystorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memorystore) for production and it works great.

[express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session#readme)